# Why is CAP_CHROOT equivalent to root?

Tags: debian, security, chroot, capabilities

I have trouble understanding the root-equivalence of `CAP_CHROOT` given the below template.

I understand that 1) means to create a directory structure, containing all dependencies (e.g. shared objects), whose root will be the target for `chroot(2)`.

My question concerns the latter steps in the template:

- Why is it necessary to backdoor `ld.so` or `libc` in 2)?
- Why is it necessary to create a hardlink to a setuid-root binary
  from the chroot environment in 3)?
- Why call `chroot(2)` to launch setuid-root binary in 4)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *necessary*, it's one way to do it.

By changing the root directory, you're invalidating the assumptions that components of the system can make.

`/bin/su` works on the assumption that the user database is in `/etc/passwd`/`/etc/shadow`, that the `libc` (or any library it's linked to) is in some fixed location in `/lib` that no ordinary user can modify.

If you're able to create a different filesystem layout where the same `/bin/su` command can be run but with a different `/etc/passwd` or different `libc` which you can modify at will, then you can do anything (as `su` uses or can use (possibly indirectly) `/etc/passwd` to authenticate user, and runs code in the libc).

Now, with that approach, having `CAP_CHROOT` is not the only thing that you need. You also need write access to a directory on a filesystem (as hardlinks can only be done *within* a given filesystem) that has at least one dynamically linked setuid-root executable.

Systems where the system partitions have no user-writable area (or even are read-only) are not uncommon. It's also common to have filesystems with user-writable areas mounted with a `nosuid` flag. Many systems also forbid hardlinking files you don't own (see the `fs.protected_hardlinks` sysctl on Linux 3.6+ for instance).

But you don't need to hardlink the setuid executable inside your chroot jail. You can also do:

```
chdir("/");
chroot("/tmp/myjail");
execl("bin/su", "su", 0);
```

as even though the root of the process is changed by `chroot`, the current working directory will still be available afterward even though that `/` directory and the `bin/su` resolved from there are not *inside* the jail. And `/bin/su` will still look for `ld.so`, `/etc/passwd` or the libc inside your jail since they are accessed via absolute paths, so relative to the *changed root* directory. Leaving the current working directory or any file descriptor open on a file outside the jail gives you a door out of the jail.

Comment: @Shuzheng, yes, you're right, you'd still be able to execute the system's `su` without hardlinking it inside your jail if you use a relative path and leave your current working directory in the original `/` or in the directory where `su` lies. See edit.

Comment: @Shuzheng,  relative paths are relative to the current working directory, which is a property of the process, so `su` would never do that. You'd need a way to express a path relative to the path of the executable, but that doesn't sound like a good idea either.

Comment: @Shuzheng `chroot` changes `/` (see `/proc/self/root`), it doesn't change `.` (see `/proc/self/cwd`)

Comment: *But you don't need to hardlink the setuid executable inside your chroot jail.* - makes it much easier for an attacker to exploit `CAP_CHROOT`. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.